# How to preprocess this image for Tesseract?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, tesseract

I’ve been trying to find a way to process this image for a long time, it’s very bad quality, clearly below 300ppi, I’m trying to process it with blur and threshold.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpJte.jpg)

All that I did, is it possible to work with this image?

```
img = cv2.imread(img_path, 0)

img = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (3, 3), 0)
_, threshold = cv2.threshold(img, 65, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
```

[Preprocessed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6nIT.png)

My goal: Take all data from this document (first name, last name, date)

Goal example:
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAj8c.png)

Comment: What is the goal of your processing? Do you need to extract text? Please be more clear. What else do you want to do? What have you tried? That image is extremely noise. But that was likely the point of the background noise/texture to prevent people from extracting that information from the license or trying to duplicated it.

Comment: @fmw42, My goal is to collect all the data, I have not tried other methods, because I am already successfully processing documents of a similar sample with higher quality using this method, but I would be glad if someone shared the best way to handle such quality

Comment: Could you add an expected output image?

Comment: @nathancy Added example

Comment: You can use [morphological operations](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html) to smooth out your image as a preprocessing step. Then isolate the ROI of the text and throw it into tesseract

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
img = cv2.imread(img_path, 0)

y=53
x=230
h=335
w=380

img = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]

img = cv2.resize(img, (0,0), fx=1.5, fy=1.5) 

img = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (3, 3), 0)
_, threshold = cv2.threshold(img, 65, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
threshold = cv2.GaussianBlur(threshold, (3, 3), 0)
```